# Getting Variables from a external .json file Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

## What I need help with

I want to receive variables from a external .json file in the local directory
using python27

(import doesn't work)

I want to store the variables in the .json like below

```
value1 = "this_is_value1"
value2 = "this_is_value2"
value3 = "this_is_value3"
```

and have them being used in a script.

If I can get it to the point of which the .json includes

```
value1 = "this_is_value1"
```

and my .py includes

```
print(value1)
```

with output

```
>>>this_is_value1
```

I can take it from there

## My end Task

The idea is that I need to change specific parts of another .yaml file, this program needs to take variables like (ID, System_id, IP) and for this case I need a .json I can change which the python27 script then pulls the information from to change the .yaml file.

I've done this part fine, just need to do  this part

## Have I researched the issue?

In short, YES.

however, theses answer use .py or other file types.

I've already tried importing the file but since it needs to sit next to the script I can't use **import**

Other anwser simply give no information back about how they solved the issue.

Comment: Why do you need them as variables? Is a `dict` not good enough?

Comment: Have a look at the `configparser` module for a safe, easy way to store this kind of config.

Comment: Either an inifile, or a json formatted file loaded into a dict should solve your issue

Comment: "... these answer[s] use .py or other file types" – but the methods do work? Then cheat. Rename your .txt file to .py, import, rename back.

Comment: Or you could use pickle, pickle.dump and pickle.load

Comment: @match I'm kinda new to python, but looking at a inifile it looks promising, Is there a good link?

Comment: @usr2564301 can you explain further?

Comment: There's a good explanation of `configparser` here: 
https://pymotw.com/3/configparser/

Comment: @Adonis I tried to format it to a json format but something wasn't correct, could you describe how this can be done?

Comment: You said you found working solutions for files that end with .py. So rename your file, even if only temporarily. I don't know what solutions you found so I cannot offer more advice than this.

Comment: renaming the file is really not necessary when there are already plenty of options for reading. Could also set environment variables there in `bash` and pull from `os.environ`

Comment: @usr2564301 I found a possible solution with keeping my variable in a .py but I could'nt import it, as it was local next to my script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a json formatted file (say "my_file.json"), for instance:

```
{
  "x": "this is x",
  "y": "this is x",
  "z": "this is z"
}
```

Then in Python:

```
import json

with open("my_file.json", "r") as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)
print(my_dict["x"])
```

Yields:

```
this is x
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to control this process with a method or function. Here is a code snip I use frequently that will read the format of the text file you've shown:

```
class MainApp(object):

    def __init__(self, config_file):
        # Initialization stuff from a configuration file.
        self.readConfigFile(config_file)

    def readConfigFile(self, file):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as cfg:
                lines = list(cfg)
            print("Read", len(lines), "lines from file", file)
            # Set configured attributes in the application
            for line in lines:
                key, value = line.split('=')
                setattr(self, key.strip(), value.strip())
        except:
            print('Configuration file read error')
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create an instance of the application.
    # It will read the configuration file provided here.
    app = MainApp('myconfig.txt')
    # Now you can access the attributes of the class (read from config file)
    print(app.value1, app.value2, app.value3)
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused about what this does, Could you please explain a little more :)

Comment: I updated the answer with a use case example. It's beneficial because the app contains all of the configured parameters as attributes of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>> string1 = 'value1 = "this_is_value1"'

>> exec(string1)

>> print(value1)
"this_is_value1"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my questions, as I wanted the "string1" variable stored in a external .txt file. I thank you though :).

Comment: You can simple read the lines of that file into strings with `f.readline()` and use this to convert it to a variable.

Comment: That's not a good idea, suppose someone writes in that text file on a line `os.removedirs("/")`

Answer (score 0):

If what you really need is a .txt file, then I recommend you to take a look at the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html
Go to section: 7.2 Reading and Writing a file

Basically, you'll need is:

```
lines = [] # for further data manipulation
file = open("c:\path\to\your.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    lines.append([line.split("=")])
file.close()
```

Now if you have in your .txt bar="foo"
Then in the lines list you can do:

```
lines[0][0] # output "bar"
lines[0][1] # output "foo"
```

Of course there are some more smater way of doing this, but this is just basic idea.